Equations of Motion for the $N$-body Problem in the Astrocentric Frame
I’ve been studying Tremaine's Dynamics of Planetary Systems and have hit a roadblock.
In Chapter 4, titled 'The $N$-body Problem,' there is a derivation of the $N$-body equations of motion, which can be expressed as follows:
$$
\ddot{\vec{r}}_{j} = \sum_{k = 0 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \left(\vec{r}_{k} - \vec{r}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}_{j} - \vec{r}_{k}|^{3}} \, , j = 0, ..., N-1. 
$$
To rewrite these equations of motion in the astrocentric frame, we introduce $\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{m} = \vec{r}_{m} - \vec{r}_{0}$. Substituting this into the equation above allows us to express it as follows:
$$
\ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = \sum_{k = 0 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \sum_{k = 1}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} 
\\
\iff \ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = - \frac{Gm_{0} \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}|^{3}} + \sum_{k = 1 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} Gm_{k}\left[\frac{\left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \frac{ \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} \right] \, , j = 0, ..., N-1. 
$$
However, Equation (4.5) in Tremaine's Dynamics of Planetary Systems includes an extra factor of $m_{j}$ in the first term. Why is that?
$$
\ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = - \frac{G\left(m_{0} + m_{j}\right)\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}|^{3}} + \sum_{k = 1 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} Gm_{k}\left[\frac{\left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \frac{ \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} \right] \, , j = 0, ..., N-1. 
$$

Note that the sum in equation (4.5) vanishes in the case N=1, resulting in the central body-centric two body equation $$\ddot {\vec r}^{,\star}_1 = -\frac{G(m_0+m_1),\vec r^{,\star}_1}{|\vec r^{,\star}_1|^3}$$This is of course the correct equation for the astrocentric two body problem. The $G{m_0+m_j)$ term does indeed belong in Tremaine's equation (4.5). See my answer for details.

I'll be quoting two of the equations in the question and addressing them in turn.

$$
\ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = \sum_{k = 0 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \sum_{k = 1}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} \, , j = 0, ..., N-1\tag{1}
$$

That is correct. Note that $\ddot{\vec r}^{\,\star}_0$ is tautologically zero from equation (1), so we might as well exclude $j=0$ as a special case (which is what I will do later on).

$$\iff \ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = - \frac{Gm_{0} \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}|^{3}} + \sum_{k = 1 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} Gm_{k}\left[\frac{\left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \frac{ \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} \right] \, , j = 0, ..., N-1 \tag{2}
$$

That is not correct, for two reasons. You have included $j=0$ (your equation (2) results in $\frac00$ for $j=0$), and you have combined sums incorrectly.
Going back to equation (1), note that the second sum in this equation includes $k=j$ for non-zero $j$. We need to single out the $k=j$ element of the second sum, resulting in
$$
\ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = - \frac{Gm_{j} \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}|^{3}} + \sum_{k = 0 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \sum_{k = 1 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} \, , j = 1, ..., N-1 \tag{3}
$$
In order to combine the two sums, the $k=0$ element in the first sum in equation (3) also needs to be treated as a special term, resulting in
$$
\ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = - \frac{G(m_{0}+m_j)\, \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}|^{3}} + \sum_{k = 1 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \sum_{k = 1 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{Gm_{k} \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} \, , j = 1, ..., N-1\tag{4}
$$
Now the two sums can be combined, resulting in
$$
\ddot{\vec{r}}^{\, \star}_{j} = - \frac{G(m_{0}+m_j)\, \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j}|^{3}} + \sum_{k = 1 \\ k \neq j}^{N-1} Gm_{k} \left(\frac{\left(\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} \right)}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{j} - \vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}} - \frac{\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}}{|\vec{r}^{\, \star}_{k}|^{3}}\right) \, , j = 1, ..., N-1\tag{5}
$$
This is equation (4.5) in Tremaine's Dynamics of Planetary Systems. Note that equations (3) to (5) exclude $j=0$. That's okay because we already know that $\ddot{\vec r}^{\,\star}_0$ is tautologically zero from equation (1).

Thank you very much!
